# How to inherit base component in Vue JS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am new to Vue JS and I have few components registered. Now I would like to know if it is possible to register a base component which can be inherited in all components so that some properties and methods can be reusable.

Component Code:

```
Vue.component("workflowtemplate", {
            template: "#workflowtemplate",
            props: {
                item: Object                
            }
        });

Vue.component("workflowsequence", {
            template: "#workflowsequencetemplate",
            props: {
                item: Object
            }
        });
```

Now, here as you can see item property has been used in all components. It is possible to have a base component wherein I can register item property and that can be accessible in all child components.

Thank you.

Comment: https://class-component.vuejs.org/guide/extend-and-mixins.html ?

Comment: @kerbholz, I am working in MVC razor file and have all components registered like mentioned above.